# Audio in sencha Touch

Tags: audio, sencha-touch, touch, sencha-touch-2

I am playing an audio track in sencha touch. Its working fine.. But I want two things.

1) How to hide audio player and autoplay the sound. For this I tried

```
autoplay:true, and 
hidden:true,
```

But this is not working ..

2) I want  to add a button for sake of playing audio i.e. It contains the text "Tap to Play" 
and when it is tapped it turns Pause .. And when pause tapped it turns to Play .. 
I have done this but It does not Work well at all.. i.e. first i have to tap play button at the player and then My customize button came into action .. 
Kindly help me to get out of this  ..

```
{
     xtype: 'audio',
     url: 'lib/touch/snd/sound.mp3',
     id: 'sound1',
     autoplay:true,
     hidden:true
},
{
     xtype: 'button',
     text:'Tap to play audio',
     handler: function() {
         var container = this.getParent().getParent(),
         // use ComponentQuery to get the audio component (using its xtype)
         audio = container.down('audio');
         audio.toggle();
         this.setText(audio.isPlaying() ? 'Pause' : 'Play');
     }
}
```

Comment: Please Now no more editing please try to sugges me a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to documentation...
[link](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Audio-event-play)

It should be something like this

```
{
 xtype: 'audio',
 url: 'lib/touch/snd/sound.mp3',
 id: 'sound1',
 autoplay:true,
 hidden:true
},
{
 xtype: 'button',
 text:'Tap to play audio',
 handler: function() {
     Ext.getCmp('#sound1').play(this,erg); or
     Ext.getCmp('#sound1').pause(this,0,erg);
 }
}
```

Comment: Well this is working but i want to hide audio player too .. It is working in Chrome but not in iPhone5 simulator .. Will you help me

Comment: do we need particulat framework for playing a video in sencha touch ?

Comment: audio player is nothing but a box with some control...dig into the css and use hidden on that particular box

Comment: well i m telling that it is hidden in google chrome but not hidden in iPhone5 simulator

Comment: sorry..m not sure about this...i never tested anything like this on iphone

Comment: Hmm its ok no problem .. anyway thanx

Comment: Hi arrest warrant r u there? I need some help regarding sencha touch

Comment: Well Buddy i want help in parsing JSON in sencha touch .. can you tell me how to parse and what is the purpose of using JSON instead of XML??

Comment: Hellow arrest warrant think u r arrested  :P

Comment: json is light and is prefered in sencha touch thats y we use json...regarding json....are u using ajax call for json...if yes then create a variable x=response.d; and parse x

Comment: I don't know anything about JSON dear If u can teach then it will be pleasure for me .. Thanx otherwise